# HTML Beginform in modal in foreach loop

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, html.beginform

I have a foreach loop that runs trough all my appointments. All of these appointments have to receive a rating which I would like the user to fill in inside a bootstrap modal. 
I've tried passing the id to the HTTPPost method without the modal which went perfectly. 
I have a feeling the data-toggle attribute is ruining it.
I know this sort of code isn't ideal but i would like the user to fill in a review without redirecting them to another page.
Is there somebody who knows how to make sure the id passed to the HTTPPost method is the correct one? Right now I always get the ID of the first appointment in the list. 
Any help is more than welcome.

```
<tbody> 
@foreach (Appointment a in Model.Appointments)
{
if (DateTime.Now > a.endingDate && Model.Account.idBabysitters.Equals(null))
{
<tr>
    <td data-name="Van" class="text-center"><p>@a.startingDate</p></td>
    <td data-name="Tot" class="text-center"><p>@a.endingDate</p></td>
    <td data-name="Prijs" class="text-center"><p>@a.fee</p></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnReview" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal">&#x2729; Geef punten</button></td>
    <td class="modalTD">
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Score", "Appointment", new { @id = a.idAppointments, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }, FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <div class="modal fade myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close btnCloseModal" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Schrijf Recensie</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Klaar!" class="btn btn-default btnCloseModal">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
}
}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I reckon your form should be inside your modal. Not modal inside your form.

Comment: @HastaPasta I have tried this but that didn't work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your btn for modal

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnReview" data-toggle="modal" data-target="@(String.Format("{0} {1}", .myModal, a.idAppointments))">&#x2729; Geef punten</button>
```

You Modal

```
 <div class="@String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}, modal, fade, myModal, a.idAppointments")" role="dialog">
```

Idea is to have a different modal class name for each of your appointments item. As for now your button is always getting the first modal it can find thus you are getting the same id in the post method.

Comment: Your solution is perfect! 
I changed it a bit (not realy familiar with the String.Format thing). I just added @a.idAppointment as the class of the modal and the class of the data-target and it worked. Thank you so much, saved me a lot of time!